# Changing to PHP 5-5.5

Tags: php, server

I've been using **`PHP-5.4.3`** for about a month now, and today, I decided to make a switch to **[PHP-5.5.5](http://www.php.net/get/php-5.5.5.tar.bz2/from/a/mirror)**, I downloaded the source code, and placed it in `C:/php` (*also renaming the folder `php-5.5.5` to `php`*) and I added server variables, as usual `C:/php/` *<-- but here I got stuck*. Because, usually I appended the `php.exe` at the end, which was found inside the PHP folder so, I could be able to access PHP from the command line, or start the built-in server, but now, I can't find this file, and I can't find a way to start the server from the command line either.

Anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

The `php-5.5.5.tar.bz2` file contains **source code** that needs to be compiled to binaries before you can use it. Since you are using Windows, why not download the binary packages provided by PHP?

From the [release announcement](http://php.net/archive/2013.php#id2013-10-16-1) (emphasis mine):

> ### PHP 5.5.5 has been released
>
> 16-Oct-2013
>
> The PHP development team announces the immediate availability of PHP
>   5.5.5. This release fixes about twenty bugs against PHP 5.5.4, some of them
>   regarding the build system. All PHP users are encouraged to
>   upgrade to this new version.
>
> For source downloads of PHP 5.5.5 please visit our [downloads page](http://php.net/downloads.php),
>   ***Windows binaries can be found on [windows.php.net/download/](http://windows.php.net/download/).***
>   The list of changes is recorded in the [ChangeLog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.5.5).

See also http://php.net/windows for installation instructions.

Comment: I have donwloaded this package. I just don't know what to do with it. How do I run it, and how can I make it accessible from the terminal?

Comment: @Simon_eQ Terminal? What OS are you using? A Linux distribution? Or Windows? Try to read the manual pages on installation.

Comment: I am using windows. I downloaded just about everything, but I can't seem to start even the built-in php server. If you have any idea, pls help

Comment: @Simon_eQ http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php

Comment: Yea, those are the instructions I followed, but I can't get somehow, what is wrong

Comment: @Simon_eQ So update your question with what you ahave tried and where you got stuck. Not "I read this page and it does not work" but "I downloaded X from ..., extracted it to ..., ran the installer, navigated to ... in Explorer, but [problem]"

Comment: You are right. Well, I have downloaded the windows Installer, and the ` » Microsoft 2008 C++ Runtime (x86)` and installed this software, but when I try to run php, from the `php.exe` it is giving me error saying "The program can't start because MSVSCR110.dll is missing from your computer "

Comment: @Simon_eQ Google for that error and you [would find out](http://serverfault.com/a/517704/51929) that you need to install the VS C++ 2012 runtime: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679